OccupancyGridMap compression in ros2
In ROS 1 we used the blob_tools package to compress OccupancyGrid messages. Is there an equivalent package or recommended approach in ROS 2 for efficiently compressing and transmitting OccupancyGrid messages?
Thank you!
